# Axios: how to prevent the GET request showing my password?

Tags: error-handling, axios, request

I've created a function to check the user's password, the request is:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3003/api/get/pwd_checking/" + userId + "/" + userPassword, {
   headers: { 'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token') }
})
.then(response => {
    // The password is correct!
})
.catch(err => alert("Wrong Password!"))
```

In case of error (mostly because of **wrong password**), I expect to get ONLY the *alert*, but, in the *Browser Developer Tools*, I also get:

```
GET http://localhost:3003/api/get/pwd_checking/346/theWrongPwd 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Even though the "**theWrongPwd**" is not the good one, but people could know most of the characters of my password (sometimes, we just misspell a single letter). How could I prevent that?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

To check password we should use POST method. Because our password data is secure which needs security. When use POST method the data is sent to server in a bundle. But in GET method data is sent to the server followed by the url like append with url request which will be seen to everyone.

So For secure authentication and authorization process we should use POST method.

I hope this solution will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Wonderful, your explanation is very clear! I didn't know that (I use "POST" for "signin" and it's similar). Thank you very much for your fast answer!